# Arduino Converting AnalogInput(0-1024) to a 1-10 scale

Tags: input, arduino, scale

I'm fairly new at coding and basically what I'm trying to do is to make a meter with a 1-10 scale using the analog inputs I get which is 0-1024. I'd like to reverse the analog inputs. Analog Input 1024 is 0 in the scale and Analog Input 0 is 10 in the scale. Sorry if this is an easy code to make but I just started coding. Thanks you!

Comment: You haven't posted anything of your code. Show us what you've tried. Also, here is ONE ideia: Use the rule of three to calculate the 1024 correspondent in the scale (`0-10` directly). Then, subtract 10 of that value and remove the negative.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the `map` function to achieve what you want.

Try something like the following:

```
int val = analogRead(0);
int newval = map(val, 0, 1023, 10, 0);
```

The first two numbers are the range of the input value and the second pair of numbers are the range you want the input to be mapped to.

Have a look at the [Arduino reference for the `map` function](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/).

**Note:** I don't have an Arduino on hand so can't double check that this works.

Answer (score 0):

This should work(I do not have the compiler on this machine to check).

```
int val;
val = 10 - (analogRead(0) / 102.4);
```